# How to access commit message with Husky pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, husky, git-husky

My husky script:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "sh ./tools/githooks/pre-commit.sh"
    }
  }
```

Let's say I am doing a `git commit -m "I want that text"`.
How can I access to my commit message within the shell script?
I tried to echo $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS and $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN within the shell script but no success

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pre-commit hook would *not* access the commit message, because the hook is triggered *before* the commit creation.

A [commit-msg hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--commit-msg.sample) is the right hook for checking a commit message content.

And it is [available with husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/e5531f1d4ca3c72148660b8ec66d502daf34dd8b/README.md#access-git-params-and-stdin) in 2019

```
"commit-msg": "echo $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
```

Update 2020, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864037/how-to-access-commit-message-with-husky-pre-commit-hook/57864128?noredirect=1#comment115043422_57864128) by [galethil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3198533/galethil)

> `HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS` is removed in version 5.
> Instead Git parameters should be used directly in scripts (e.g. `$1`)

---

Note, since 2019, [commit c4e1ed1](https://github.com/typicode/husky/commit/c4e1ed110644eb9942ddef046af0aeb8119c9262) (Dec. 2020, Husky v5.0.5) mentions:

> Previous `HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS` environment variable is **replaced** by native params `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: `HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS` is removed in version 5. Instead Git parameters should be used directly in scripts (e.g. $1) .

Comment: @galethil Thank you for this update. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I think this doesn't work in 7.x. I echo $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS from inside my script and its empty.

Comment: @jcollum I agree. I have edited the answer to include the evolution.

Comment: well I'm not getting git params either :/  https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1141

Answer (score 0):

A solution that has worked for me (ubuntu:22.04)

In the .husky folder add a bash script, for example "commit-msg", to print the message like in this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

commit_message="$(cat "$1")"

echo $commit_message
```